# How to get the number of desired nodes and their coordinates from user in matlab?

Tags: matlab, input

It might be a silly question, but I'm not really good at matlab and I don't know how to get input from the user.
I'm writing code which is supposed to get `n` nodes and their coordinates from the user, then find the Hamiltonian path. Here is what I think, please tell me where I'm wrong.

```
n=input('\nPlease enter the number of nodes: \n')
for i:1:n
  pos[]=input('\nPlease enter their coordinates. \n')
end
x=pos(:,1);
y=pos(:,2);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you meant that

```
pos[]=input('\nPlease enter their coordinates. \n')
```

should be changed to

```
pos(i)=input('\nPlease enter their coordinates. \n')
```

but pos won't have two columns so perhaps this is better:

```
for i:1:n
  x(i)=input('\nPlease enter X coordinate. \n')
  y(i)=input('\nPlease enter Y coordinate. \n')
end
```

then to store in a single array do the following after the loop:

```
A = [x, y]
```

Comment: You were right dear friend, but the problem is i don't know how to store A(x,y) into an array(n,2). some thing like this: array(x1 y1,x2 y2,x3 y3,....)

Comment: See my edit on how to do that. However that's pretty basic Matlab syntax, I think if you're asking that you should run through a basic tutorial on Matlab before you continue

Comment: You're right, it was my last idiotic post here..Sorry and thank you.

Comment: No problem, but I do think you should run through a quick tut just to get an idea of the syntax and the structure of the language as it can be quite different to a lot of common languages you might be used to